# Unstable Saving Error VB.net, mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

My code for saving is unstable sometimes it saves and sometimes it gives this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's' , '50931213' , '50' , '7.20' , '7.42' , '7.78' , '08-13-2016' , '07-19-2018' ' at line 1

Could you guys help me debug?
Here's my code:

Dim cmd3 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            con.Open()

```
        query = "INSERT INTO tblproduct(ProductNo, GenericName, BrandName, CompanyNo, Quantity, BuyingPrice, WholesalePrice, RetailPrice, PurchasedDate, ExpirationDate, Status)VALUES('" _
            & txt_prodno.Text & "' , '" _
            & cmb_gname.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_bname.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_comno.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_quantity.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_bprice.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_wprice.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_rprice.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_pdate.Text & "' , '" _
            & txt_edate.Text & "' , '" _
            & cmb_status.Text & "')"

        cmd3 = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Product Saved!", vbInformation)

        loadrec()
        con.Close()
```

Ok. The debugger pointed at:

i As Integer = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

and started at txt_comno which is CompanyNo down to txt_edate which is ExpirationDate.

I suspected that I messed up with my data fields matching and quotes but everything is in place. As I have said earlier I can save records. How ever there are times that this error would occur making it an unstable saving function..

Comment: You have the best debugging environment in the world. And you know what data makes it blow up. So go into debug mode.

Comment: The debugger pointed at this line:
 i As Integer = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

I suspected I messed up with my data fields or quotes but everything seems to be in placed.

Comment: right before the call to that nonquery, examine the string `query ` ... get its contents and show it via an [edit]